# How to detect if a data frame has nan values in MATLAB?

Tags: python, pandas, matlab

I am new to Matlab and Python. Currently I am working on some assignment where I want to check if data frame has nan values in matlab or not?

Comment: Is this question really about Matlab? The accepted answer and the name "dataframe" suggest it's actually Python / Pandas. Please modify the tags if appropriate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [python](/questions/tagged/python) with [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) you can use below code:

```
> df.isnull().any().any()
True

>df.isnull().sum().sum()
89
```